# Missing JavaFX application class

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have java code like this:

```
package mypackage;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyApp extends Application{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

and I've compiled it at `~/myjava/src/mypackage/MyApp.class` .
then, when I'm running from

```
~$ java -cp myjava/src mypackage/MyApp
```

why getting error like:

```
Missing JavaFX application class mypackage/MyApp
```

I'm using JDK 8.

Comment: use `cp` as `myjava/src` seems suspicious. Is that the directory with the `.class` files? (I would expect `myjava/build` or something like that)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is because you are calling your application with a directory path instead of the fully qualified classname. The fully qualified classname is composed from the package name and the class name. In your case this is `mypackage.MyApp`.

Assuming that your compiled class resides in the same folder as the source `.java` file, call it this way:

```
java -cp myjava/src mypackage.MyApp
```

Comment: thank you @hotzst , it work fine. I think '/' and '.' is same, but it was different :)

Comment: Or, in my case, I had specified a classpath for a jar file and not the -cp ".;myjar.jar" that I needed...

Answer (score 1):

After installing Java 15 and JavaFX 13 and some other changes I too was getting "Missing JavaFX application class mypackage/MyApp" and in my case the package name and application were correct. I was using some JDK15 preview functions and I needed the JVM option --enable-preview. In desperation I started to change things, as this used to work. When I removed the --enable-preview option I received error messages relating to the fact I was using preview functions and did not specify it. This told me the loader was in fact finding my application. The error message "Missing JavaFX application class mypackage/MyApp" was incorrect in this case. The problem was I needed to include some user utility classes that MyApp was dependent upon. Once I included the dependent classes in the classpath all was well.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. While the `--enable-preview` flag could help with some issues such as the one that you have described ("I was using preview functions"), unfortunately forgetting the flag will *not* give the error but the following one instead: `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for ... (class file version ...). Try running with '--enable-preview'` (see https://nipafx.dev/enable-preview-language-features/#same-version-for-feature-compiler-and-jvm)