# Error: "missing JavaFX application class" when starting from Eclipse

Tags: java, javafx

I work with JavaFX and try to run my Code but i get "missing JavaFX application class" error.
I add JVM Arguments for javafx.controlls and javafx.fxml. I also use another Libary called "dyn4j" but i don't think this is the trigger for the error.

This is how my Code looks:

```
public class DropToTheBottom extends Application {



private Pane pane;
    private World<MyPhysicsBody> world;
    private Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().add(pane);

        scene = new Scene(root, Settings.SCENE_WIDTH, Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        pane.getTransforms().add(new Translate(Settings.SCENE_WIDTH / 2, Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT));
        pane.getTransforms().add(new Scale(Settings.SCALE, -Settings.SCALE));

        world = new World<>();
        world.setGravity(World.EARTH_GRAVITY);

        Controller controller = new Controller(pane, world);

        // creates a floor on the bottom of the screen
        world.addBody(controller.createRectangle(new Vector2(1, 0), scene.getWidth(), 1, Color.RED, MassType.INFINITE));

        // create rectangle bodies and add them to the world
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            world.addBody(
                    controller.createRectangle(new Vector2(0, 10), 1, 1, Color.BLUE, MassType.NORMAL, 0.8, 1.2, 0.5));
        }

        world.addBody(controller.createCircle(0, 5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, MassType.NORMAL, Color.RED, false));
        world.addBody(controller.createCircle(2, 5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, MassType.NORMAL, Color.BLUE, true));

        controller.startAnimation();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I hope anyone can help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you show us the entire error? TIA

Comment: Does your code compile? What java version are you using and what Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308480/missing-javafx-application-class

Comment: show your build output or stacktrace.

Comment: My code compile and I only get the red error message: "Missing JavaFX application class mySamples.DropToTheBottom" I use Eclipse version 4.15.0

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by my self. I created a new Project with new Java files, but with the same name and copied only the code to the new Java fiels. I don't know why this solved my issue but it did.